# Problem with touchpad pointer

Tags: touchpad

Hello I'm a new user of elementary os. It is a beautiful OS, maybe the best in my opinion, but I have a little problem with the pointer when I use it with touchpad. 
For example when I place the pointer on the X of close, the pointer moves involuntarily. This problem is reapeted since I have installed the OS, on all parts of the display.
I have a Fujitsu Lifebook. 
Can anyone help me, please? Thanks for the attention.

PS- sorry for the language but I'm not english. I hope you can understand me